# You have something/anything in mind?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language, some-vs-any

A: Don't you think a bit of distraction might be good for you?

B: I don't know.

A: Well, if you want to do something sometime, just let me know.

B: **...You have something/anything in mind?**

A: No, I just thought you might want to get out a little.

I know the difference between 'something' and 'anything' but would one of them for some reason seem more natural than the other in this context?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [some and any in questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/328473/113306)?

Comment: That is a very good summary that explains the nuanced difference between some and any

Answer (score 0):

To me, both of these sound natural, and it seems to me like something that someone would actually say. The only thing I would add is ‘do’ at the start:

> **Do** you have anything in mind?
> **Do** you have something in mind?

Another thing: Saying ‘something might’ imply you are looking for something more specific.

Comment: `Do` is more formal, but in informal spoken english dropping it fine.

Answer (score 0):

They have slightly different meanings.

In your case, person B is asking person A if they are thinking of a specific thing, of some thing. Person A in these situations has implied that they are thinking of a specific thing: "*if you want to do **something** sometime, just let me know*". It wouldn't make sense to refer to that 'something' as just anything.

"*You have anything in mind?*" is more of a general inquiry, e.g. "*Did you have anything in mind for Helen's present?*" (taken from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-something-in-mind)).

The first idiom is also more common according to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=something%20in%20mind%2Canything%20in%20mind&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 0):

"Do you have **something** in mind?" **is specific**.

Answer: "Yes, I was thinking we could play a video game."

Do you have **anything** in mind? **is not specific**.
That could refer to any number of suggestions. play a video game, watch a movie, go for a walk.